# Is it possible to turn "ERROR No tests to run" in to a Warning?

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, circleci, web-testing, testcafe

I'm running TestCafe via CircleCi as part of my CI/CD process, using "Smoke" test-meta tags (in order to run a subset of our regression tests every build deploy).

As part of the run, CircleCi splits the test suites/specs to run on different containers in parallel, resulting in:

```
testcafe chrome:headless tests/someFolder/someTestSuite.js --test-meta smoke=true
```

Not every suite will contain a "Smoke" test, however, so those will fail with 'ERROR No tests to run. Either the test files contain no tests or the filter function is too restrictive'.

Is there a way to switch this to a warning, rather than a failure? I've tried using the `--disable-test-syntax-validation` flag, but this understandably doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do this via a public API.  You can consider defining a [custom filter](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/runner.html#filter) or adding some empty tests with `meta='smoke'` to avoid this error.

Comment: Thanks, a custom filter might be the way to go.

Comment: @RobC How did you solve this problem? we can't provide custom filter via command line

Comment: @Vinay I accepted this answer because there is no way to do this via the API. I haven't had a chance to look at a custom filter yet, but if I do (and it works), I'll post the solution here